# Dynamic Select Field that Repopulates after Changes in Another Select Field - Laravel 5.2 and JS

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

I am developing a web app using Laravel 5 and trying to integrate some JS to help out a form. I want users to be able to select a category in one select field, at which point a second select field should populate with options within that category. (E.g., Select a profession: programmer, artist. If 'programmer' is selected, second select field populates with: C++, Java, Python. If 'artist' is selected, second select populates with: Photoshop, Illustrator, MS Paint.)

Note that I need to populate these fields from my database. I've found examples of what I am trying to do on the web that I have tried to adapt to my case. The one I'm using is here: http://www.9lessons.info/2010/08/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using.html but I can't get it to work (it's fairly old--from 2010).

Here's my HTML and JS:

```html
<!-- JS -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#field_main").change(function()
{
  var id = $(this).val();
  var fields="";
  $.ajax
  ({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax_field.php",
    data: {id: id},
    cache: false,
    success: function(data)
        {
           $.each(data,function(index,field) 
           {
             fields+="<option value='"+field.id+"'>"+field.field+"</option>";
           });
           $("#field").html(fields);
       }
   });
 });
});
</script>

<!-- Create the first select field, this part of the code works fine -->
<label>Area :</label>
<select name="field_main" id="field_main">
   <option selected="selected">--Select Area--</option>
   <?php
   $areas = App\Area::all();
   foreach($areas as $area){
      echo "<option value=\"" . $area->id . "\">" . $area->area . "</option>";
    }
   ?>
</select>

<!-- Create the second select field; this part is not working -->
<label>Field :</label>
<select name="field" id="field">
<!--<option selected="selected">--Select Field--</option>-->

</select>
```

Here's what ajax_field.php looks like:

```html
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use DB;

if($_POST['id'])
{
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $fields = DB::table('fields')->where('area_ref', $id)->get();
    return response()->json(['data' => ['fields' => $fields]]);
}
?>
```

As far as I can tell, nothing runs from ajax_skill.php. I tried echoing something out in that function, it didn't appear on my page, and the skills field never populates. The profession select field, however, populates fine.

Any thoughts on where this code is going wrong?

Comment: The immediate problem is that you set a post parameter with the key `id` yet attempt to retrieve it with the (non existent) key `profession`, but there are a number of other issues - read a few beginning laravel tutorials, and get a handle on basic MVC, routing etc first.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return JSON when hitting that URL with AJAX. You don't need the HTML. Return only the skills data with `return response()->json(['data' => ['skills' => $skills]]);` and add the select element on the page populated with all of the skills.

Oh and, the ajax data property takes an object so it should be: `data: {id: id}`

Since you are using Laravel, half of your code looks like old school PHP which is useless when Laravel has a cleaner way for these things.

If you are new to PHP and Object Oriented Programming, I'd advice you to learn that before using Laravel. It will help you in the future.

Also, I'd advice you to read up the [Laravel](http://laravel.com) documentation, follow the tutorials there and even go to [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com) and watch the Laravel 5 Fundamentals and Laravel From Scratch series to get up to speed with Laravel.

Comment: Thanks. Are you saying that I should remove the foreach statement in ajax_skill and return JSON there instead? The HTML in the first bit of code is indeed on the main view page. Yes, I understand your suggestion to work on my PHP before using Laravel. That's part of why I am not coding everything using Laravel shortcuts. I want to try to learn some of the PHP at the same time while taking advantage of Laravel's authentication framework and such.

Comment: Or do you mean instead of the $(".skill").html(html); function

Comment: Yup, remove the foreach and return json instead. You'll construct the HTML inside the AJAX success() function.

Comment: Okay. I made some edits above given your and Steve's comments. If I can just fill in the ellipses in the function with some sort of foreach statement it should work?

Comment: Made a few more edits based on some additional code I found elsewhere. Please let me know if I'm getting close at all. It's hard to figure out what I need to research to get it working because I am not sure which part of the code is a problem. Laravel does not seem to offer any error reporting on any of this, and I don't even have any indication that ajax_field.php is ever getting loaded/run.

Comment: Check your chrome dev tools (or the browser's dev tools you are using), go to network and see the request information.

Comment: The log does not change when I make the selection that's supposed to populate the second field. I also get an error report: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(anonymous function) @ startproject:138, which corresponds to the following in the above code: $(document).ready(function()

Comment: Do you have jquery added on the main page?

Comment: Yes, but the load script for jquery came after the script that loads the select field. Your question got me thinking that I should changed the order of the scripts, and now I'm getting something in the request information when I make a selection. That is a good sign! It's still not working, but I will troubleshoot it a bit and report back shortly.

Comment: I seem to have a namespace problem: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in <br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Class 'DB' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\arc\public\ajax_field.php:8         I am not seeing the problem with the namespace as I've entered it in the code above. After searching other Stackexchange questions, people seem to say that one should be able to use DB from the controllers directory.

Comment: I'd never mix Laravel and pure PHP just for the sake of a feature or 2 from the framework but that's just me. I don't know how to help you mixing the two together. If you really wanna learn PHP, build stuff yourself to familiarize with the language and later on use a framework to see the difference.